# Debugging PHP in CodeLobster increases performance...?

Tags: php, performance, apache, debugging

When I start debugging my PHP scripts in CodeLobster my website runs extremely fast (pages load almost instantly), but when I stop debugging there is a consistent 1 second delay between page load.  1 second isn't bad at all for a page load, but it's very confusing as to why it loads instantly when I debug.

I'm kind of new to PHP and Apache, so I'm not sure which one is actually causing the problem.  I'm not sure if this would help, but here is a screencap of my CodeLobster debug settings:

[image: codelobster settings]

It's just really confusing because usually debugging has more overhead and causes slower performance.  I want to have my site to run this fast all the time; any ideas on what could cause this weird issue?  A setting in php.ini or httpd.conf maybe?

Comment: 1 second for the page to load is actually pretty poor in most cases loading a page from a server running on localhost.

Comment: When I said 1 second wasn't bad for a page load I meant that in a real world sense. I know 1 second is bad on localhost which is why I don't understand how debugging causes it to load faster.

Comment: What happens if you execute the script by command line? What does the script contain? Is it a simple "hello world" or something more advanced with database queries, *et al*? I am unfamiliar with CodeLobster, but what if you uninstall it? Does that speed things up?

Comment: My web pages are kind of advanced, with database calls, loops, and sometimes recursion.  But running these while debugging they still load instantly.  I ran a very simple test script from the command line with a for loop that iterates only 100 times, and it takes about a full second for it to output the data from the script.  From this test it seems like it's PHP and not Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debugging extension that is installed with CodeLobster is what was causing the issue.  I commented out the following lines from the `php.ini` file to disable the debugger:

```
[CLDbg]
;extension=php_cl_dbg_5_5_VC11_x64.dll
;clport=6000
```

If I want to use the debugger I just have to uncomment those lines and I can debug in CodeLobster again.  It's kind of a workaround, but I emailed CodeLobster support about the issue and I'll leave a comment here if I hear back from them.